# Offline/online mode for data sync - firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed an Android APP based on Firestore for DB storing data.

The User wants to control manually (through a button placed on the APP) the switch between off-line (no synchronization with firestore server) 
and on-line (synchronization enabled with firestore server) mode.

Is there a specific Firestore API to switch on/off firestore data synchronization local/remote?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/support on this matter :)

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime database has two functions for managing the connection manually, these are `goOffline` and `goOnline`.

Right now, it doesn't look like Firestore has similar functions as the ones listed above.  You can dig through their documentation, but looking at the Firestore object and various settings and configuration objects there are no similar calls.

Comment: I checked documentation and I didn't find anything - Does anyone know if these functions are planned in future releases?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if this is what you are looking for... https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

At the end of the documentation, there is 'Disable and enable network access' and do the following actions.

Eg. Code in Kotlin

```
db.disableNetwork().addOnCompleteListener {
    // Do offline things
    // ...
}

db.enableNetwork().addOnCompleteListener {
    // Do online things
    // ...
}
```

Let me know if you were able your feature work with this code.